# Set predifined tags to TagIt jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, tag-it

I am using https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it this plugin and have troubles to set predefined tags to it.

So, if I have array of tags that I want to be selected by default:

```
     function PredifinedTagsSet(tags) {

            for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                var el = ""; 
                el  = "<li class=\"tagit-choice\">\n";
                el += tags[i] + "\n";
                el += "<a class=\"close\">x</a>\n";
                el += "<input type=\"hidden\" style=\"display:none;\" value=\""+tags[i]+"\" name=\"item[tags][]\">\n";
                el += "</li>\n";

                var el = ""; 
                el = "<li class=\"tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all tagit-choice-editable\"><span class=\"tagit-label\">";
                el += tags[i];
                el += "</span><a class=\"tagit-close\"><span class=\"text-icon\">×</span><span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-close\"></span></a></li>";
                $("#myTags").prepend(el);
            }}
```

My tag container:

```
<div class="tags-container">
    <input type="hidden" name="tags" id="mySingleField" value=""/> 
    <label>Tags:</label>
    <ul id="myTags">
    </ul>
</div>
```

And tag-it jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTags').tagit({
        availableTags: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Tags)),
        singleField: true,
        singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField')
    });
});
```

I tried to set data to  `<ul id="myTags"></ul>` and  `<input type="hidden" name="tags" id="mySingleField" value=""/>` with javascript, but I can't remove tag from tag bar or I get duplicate value.

```
    var hiddenTagsValue  = "";
    if(tags.length > 0){
        hiddenTagsValue += tags[0];

        if(tags.length > 1)
            for(var i = 1; i < tags.length; i++) {
            hiddenTagsValue += ", ";           
            hiddenTagsValue += tags[i];
        }
    }

    $("#mySingleField").val(tags[]);
```